# Select SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polylines that have arcs?

Tags: geometry, oracle-dbms, st-geometry, true-curves, attribute-rules

Oracle 18c/10.7.1 EGDB:

I have an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polyline feature class.

Some of the polylines in the feature class have arcs.

[image]

---

Question:

Is there a way to use Oracle SDE.ST_GEOEMTRY functions to select polylines with arcs?

I've [looked through the docs](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-astext.htm), but haven't been able to find any functions that pertain to segment types.

---

Related:

[Given the line between points 1 and 2, what is the change in angle to point 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013505/given-the-line-between-points-1-and-2-what-is-the-change-in-angle-to-point-3)

Comment: CAD data is hidden in the CAD object. You cannot access it via SQL.

Comment: Computer-Aided Design or Computer-Aided Drafting

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would be a possible workaround:

1. Create a field in the feature class called `HAS_CURVES`.
2. Populate the field in real-time/when a user creates or modifies a feature -- using a Calculation Attribute Rule.

   - Compare `$feature.shape_length`, which is the true length, including true curves
   - `vs.`
   - `Length($feature)`, which is the pre-densified length, where true curves have been converted into straight segments. A screenshot of some testing I did: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilJrg.png
   - If there is a difference between those two values, then that tells us that the line has curves. Use a Calculation Attribute Rule to set the HAS_CURVES field to "Y", or 1, or whatever applies.
3. The `HAS_CURVES` field would be available to SQL. So we could query on it to find lines with curves.

Disclaimer: It's possible that comparing the those lengths might not work in all scenarios (due to rounding complications, etc.). Testing would be needed.

Related:

- [Idea: Determine if line has true curves via SQL (SDE.ST_GEOMETRY in Oracle)](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-ideas/determine-if-line-has-true-curves-via-sql-sde-st/idc-p/1149482#M2738)
- [Idea: hasCurve Arcade geometry property](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/hascurve-arcade-geometry-property/idc-p/1149417)